# Xcode 5 - iOS - How to Create a View Controller in Xcode without Storyboard or XIB and how to configure it into AppDelegate as the root view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview, appdelegate

Right I had taken a break from iOS dev and I have come back into the mix and am having issues with the following:

I want to create a View Controller with an embedded UIWebView programatically without any xib or storyboard dependancy but I can't remember for love nor money how to get the AppDelegate to show my View Controller.

Under all the documentation All I can find is placing the below under my AppDelegate

```
self.window = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"blah" bundle: nil];
```

But As I don't have any xib's associated to my ViewController files this would be useless.

Could someone please set me back on the right path.

Thanks

Comment: There is no magic at all involved.  You simply define your custom VC and have it's `loadView` method create all the components that would have been defined by the XIB.  Then `viewDidLoad` should size and position the components appropriately.  Often this is simpler than mucking with an XIB for a case that the XIB doesn't represent well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `AppDelegate.m`:

```
CustomViewController *rootViewController = [CustomViewController new];

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

In `CustomViewController.m` override:

```
- (void)loadView {
    //Configure your view
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    //other stuff
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    UIButton *button = /* alloc init etc. */
    [self.view addSubview:button];
}
```

Comment: Thank tried your suggestion and I am getting nothing but a black screen (no errors in the console) I think adding my code set might help, give me a mo...

Comment: under AppDelegate.m:        `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    
    ViewController *rootViewController = [ViewController new];
    self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}`

Comment: under ViewController.m:       
`-(void)loadView
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    
    webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]]];
    
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
}
`

Comment: apologies for the formatting issues, Its been a while since I was on SO

Comment: Man..you have to configure the view...is normal..and also did you write all the right code? see my updated answer..for example now i set a red color as background..now you see your view? ;)

Comment: Dude you are a legend! thank you so much! Cant believe I missed it

Comment: just out of curiosity, why do i need to set `[rootViewController.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];` ?

Comment: you can do that also in loadView. See my updated answer. Anyway, use loadView just to configure the view.

Comment: Right I gotcha, so essentially I created the View but didn't actually set anything to act as a background to the view for the UIWebView to stick against.

Answer (score 0):

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, CLLocationManagerDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {
    //create a location manager
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

```
//menu button
@IBOutlet weak var menu: UIBarButtonItem!

@IBOutlet weak var locationTextField: UITextField!{
    didSet {
        locationTextField.delegate = self
        locationTextField.text = ""
    }
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return globalSearchText.searchArrayLocation.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, performAction action: Selector, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, withSender sender: AnyObject?) {
    locationTextField.text = globalSearchText.searchArrayLocation[indexPath.row]
}
```